# react can't get function as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get value from component B in component A. Says B is a child of component A, so usually what ppl do is pass a function as prop to function B right? but I did not see any function in component B when I do `console.log(this.props)`

Assume my component B is named CalendarMonth , so in my render method of component A I do `<CalendarMonth getSelected={this.getSelected}`

then in CalendarMonth's I do this.props I don't see anything?

Comment: That is how it normally works.  If you want more specific help then you will need to post some code.

Comment: @AlexYoung imagine I have 4 level of nested component, how you would handle this?

Comment: Personally if I had 4 levels of nested components and was passing props/callbacks up and down between them I would use a state-management library (redux) to deal with the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

That could be multiple things - it would be better if you could post the full code.
Anyway, the most common error in that case is if the function that's calling `console.log(this.props)` is in a different context (i.e. the keyword `this` refers to something else in there, *not* your component.

If it's happening in an event handler, you should try calling `.bind`. Example:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
```